# How to change Keyboard Layouts in iPhone and iPad from a xib file?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard, extensibility

I am designing a custom keyboard for iOS devices.

I have designed a xib file that works best under iPhone devices.
But, I now realized the iPad keyboard is different from iPhone keyboard (Extra buttons and stuffs.).

Simply, can you suggest me on how I should move on with fixing this step.

My personal view on this, is to switch the xib file for keyboard by checking for device type on runtime. This does mean I design a new layout for the iPad version.

Any solutions to this?

**Edit/Update:**

I have a working iPhone keyboard using .xib file. I am using default size classes (wAny, hAny). I need the keyboard to have extra buttons for iPad only, And, keep using the same layout for the iPhone.

Comment: are u using autolayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make another xib just use the same with size classes.Using size classes you can make a whole different view with different constraints and subviews and ios will automatically render the view in different devices or orientations.And the cool thing about is you don't have to worry about code for views.Just see this example 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started.If you have any questions let me know

Comment: The iPhone and iPad have different keyboard layouts. Also, the iPad keyboard has more keys on the keyboard than the iPhone version. 

I already have a working keyboard for the iPhone. Can I specify it for the iPad version using size classes i.e. add new buttons for iPad only.?

Please describe the answer further!

Comment: @SumanAdhikari Be default you give constraints on any any size class if u change size class to ipad if you add any subviews in ipad size classes those whose won't render on iphone.Just go through the link that i gave you and if you still don't understand ping on skype.

Comment: Thank you! Size classes were the troublemakers. I finally implemented size classes properly. And, now they are working fine!

Comment: Sir, I am having a 4-5 second delay when loading the custom keyboard in device! Could you give some advice on this? I tried just creating 10-12 buttons on a new project as well. It has the same issue as well!

Comment: Are you setting images in button??

Comment: No,all are just titles for UIButton. I have found its an issue with Auto Layout for me. It's what slowing me down.

Comment: I don't think so that autolayout is the problem here.

Comment: I am using stackviews...Could that be  the problem ?? I am already having weird layout issues with the use of stackviews. It's auto generated layouts keep breaking.

Comment: I haven't used stackviews.I just went through them it doesn't seem to be a problem.Look at this tutorial and see if you didn't mess anything up https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: And i would suggest asking a new question on stackoverflow so that more people can help you.